# laplace transform of $t^nf(t)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

I have:

$$\mathcal{L}(t^nf(t)) = \int_0^\infty t^nf(t)e^{-st}\ dt = \left(-\dfrac{d}{ds}\right)^n \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}$$

I don't understand where the derivative came from

Comment: I think you mean $$\bigg (- \frac{d}{ds} \bigg)^{n}$$ not $$\bigg (- \frac{d}{dx} \bigg)^{n}$$ and this just comes from taking the derivative of $e^{-st}$ $n$ times, which gives $(-t^{n}) e^{-st}$.

Comment: yes sorry that's what I meant. i still don't follow however on the result, why is the derivative outside of the integral?

Comment: It's just a particular way of denoting the _differentiation of a parameter integral_ (the parameter here being $s$). As long as the function being integrated has certain properties, which I won't go into, you can differentiate inside the integral. In this case you can differentiate, so you could write it like $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \bigg( - \frac{d}{ds} \bigg)^{n} e^{-st} dt$$ if you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Calling $\mathcal{L}(f(t)) =F(s)$ and observing that
$$
\frac{d^n}{ds^n}\mathrm e^{-st}= (-1)^nt^n \mathrm e^{-st}
$$
we have
$$F^{(n)}(s)= \int_0^\infty f(t) \left(\frac{d^n}{ds^n}e^{-st}\right)\mathrm dt =\int_0^\infty f(t) \left((-1)^nt^n \mathrm e^{-st}\right)\mathrm dt= (-1)^n \int_0^\infty t^nf(t)e^{-st}\ dt$$
that is
$$(-1)^nF^{(n)}(s)= \int_0^\infty t^nf(t)e^{-st}\ dt =\mathcal{L}(t^nf(t)) $$